# Resize cell after scrolling (Autolayout)

Tags: swift, autolayout

Resize cell size after some scrolling.

[image]

**CommentViewController.swift Code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tblView.register(UINib(nibName: "CellComment", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellComment")

    // Remove extra space from group tableview
    var frame = CGRect.zero
    frame.size.height = .leastNormalMagnitude
    tblView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: frame)

    tblView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 123

    tblView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0.01
    tblView.separatorColor = .clear
    tblView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}

// UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 15
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellComment", for: indexPath) as! CellComment
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.imgViewUser.image = UIImage.init(named: "userImage1.jpg")
    cell.lblUserName.text = "User Name \(indexPath.row + 1)"

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.lblComment.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    }
    else {
        cell.lblComment.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."

    }
    //        cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded() //I try but not working
    //        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.layoutSubviews()
    return cell
}
```

**CellComment.swift**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //lblComment.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = lblComment.bounds.width
        lblComment.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = lblComment.bounds.size.width
    }
```

[**Full Video**](https://youtu.be/vb2ZPNwK3cE)

Answer (score 0):

It's because tableview is not able to calculate cell's frame correctly. You don't need to call cell.layoutSubviews(). You should check your constraints of contentView of tableview cell.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this cell.layoutSubviews() and add this protocol .

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Add constraints like this.[image]